default treeList and dataGrid delete confirmation buttons
I have problem in customize the localization text for Yes and No default buttons to confirm delete in treeList and DataGrid in devexpress in an asp.net core project. Is there any solution to activate localization on those buttons dialog?

I'm expecting to find a solution to find away to solve this issue for mutliple razor pages without modifying each razor page that contains the devexpress component.
example :
@using DevExtreme.AspNet.Mvc;

@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@using MainApp.Localization
@using MainApp.Web.Pages.AuthFiles
@using System.Globalization;
@using System.Threading;

@inject IStringLocalizer<MainAppResource> L

@{
}
<link href="~/css_dx/devextreme/dx.common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<abp-script-bundle name="DocSysDevExpressScriptBundle" />
<abp-style-bundle name="DocSysDevExpressStyleBundle" />

@{
    var moduleName = Model.moduleName;
    var previewRelatedDocuments = Model.previewRelatedDocuments;
    var approveBool = Model.approveBool;
    String langName = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
    var rtlBool = false;
    if (langName.Equals("ar"))
    {


        rtlBool = true;
    }
    else
    {
        rtlBool = false;
    }

  
}

<abp-style-bundle>
    <abp-style src="/client-proxies/DocsysCss.css" />
</abp-style-bundle>

@(
Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<MainApp.Topics.TopicDto>()
.ID("gridContainer").DataSource(new JS("topicsGrid_dataSource"))
.OnSaving("onSaving")
.RtlEnabled(rtlBool)
.Selection(s => s.Mode(SelectionMode.Multiple))
.OnSelectionChanged("selection_changed")

.Columns(columns =>
{


    columns.AddFor(m => m.topic_Control_Code).Caption(@L["TopicControlCode"].Value);
    if (moduleName == "Libsys"){
        columns.AddFor(m => m.topic_Name_Ar).Caption(@L["TopicNameAr"].Value);
        columns.AddFor(m => m.topic_Name_En).Caption(@L["TopicNameEn"].Value);
        columns.AddFor(m => m.topicTypeLibsys).Lookup(x => x.DataSource(topicTypeEntities)
                     .ValueExpr("id")
                     .DisplayExpr("text"))
                     .Caption(@L["AuthorType"].Value);
    }

    else
    {
        if (rtlBool)
        {
            columns.AddFor(m => m.topic_Name_Ar).Caption(@L["TopicName"].Value);
            columns.AddFor(m => m.topic_Name_En).Caption(@L["TopicName"].Value).Visible(false);

        }
        else
        {
            columns.AddFor(m => m.topic_Name_En).Caption(@L["TopicName"].Value);
            columns.AddFor(m => m.topic_Name_Ar).Caption(@L["TopicName"].Value).Visible(false);

        }

        columns.AddFor(m => m.docsCount).Caption(@L["DocsCount"].Value)
    .AllowEditing(false);
    }
    columns.AddFor(m => m.synonyms).Caption(@L["Synonym"].Value).Visible(false);
    columns.AddFor(m => m.isApproved).Caption(@L["IsApproved"].Value).Visible(false);
    columns.Add().Type(GridCommandColumnType.Buttons)
    .Buttons(b =>
    {
        b.Add()
           .Hint(@L["RelatedDocumentsReview"].Value)
           .Icon("docfile")  // You can choose any appropriate icon
           .OnClick("onRelatedDocumentsClick")
           .Visible(new JS("hasRelatedDocuments"));

        b.Add().Name(GridColumnButtonName.Edit).Visible(Model.editBool);

        b.Add().Name(GridColumnButtonName.Delete).Visible(Model.deletetBool);
       
    });


})
.ColumnChooser(cc => cc.Enabled(false))
.Editing(editing =>
{
    editing.Mode(GridEditMode.Popup);

    editing.AllowUpdating(Model.editBool);
    editing.AllowAdding(Model.addBool);
    editing.UseIcons(true);
    editing.AllowDeleting(Model.deletetBool);
    editing.Texts(t =>
 {
     t.ConfirmDeleteMessage(@L["DeleteMsg"].Value);
     t.ConfirmDeleteTitle(@L["Delete"].Value);
     t.DeleteRow(@L["Delete"].Value);
     t.SaveRowChanges(@L["Save"].Value);
     t.CancelRowChanges(@L["Cancel"].Value);

     t.AddRow(@L["Add"].Value);
     t.EditRow(@L["Edit"].Value);

 });
    editing.Popup(p => p
    .Title(@L["Topics"].Value)
    .CloseOnOutsideClick(true)
    .ShowTitle(true)

    .Width(645)
    .Height(455)
    .ResizeEnabled(true)
    .OnInitialized("onShowing")



);


Per my understanding, if we are able to modifty the content, we could do just like what you can do such as t.AddRow(@L["Add"].Value); to achieve localization. If the content is not able to be customized, we could only try to find built-in feature. For DevExtreme DataGrid, I found this case which points to this link,

it requires to load script <script src="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/24.1.7/js/localization/dx.messages.de.js"></script> and set language DevExpress.localization.locale(locale);   Could you pls try it? Here's a demo, you can see that the cancel and save button content are not defined in dictionary, but it could work after switching the lanuage.

I tried this solution and its working but only for 1 page, I need to modify many razor pages like too many more than 150

Thank you for your update, may I know whether you tried to put the scripts and DevExpress.localization.locale("de"); in layout or some other similar views?

You can put all the scripts into _Layout.cshtml and then you don't need to refer them in every single pages, but you might need to surround the  like @section Scripts{<script></script>}

When we want to apply localization into js components, when we do like what you had done for variables managed by ourselves such as t.AddRow(@L["Add"].Value);. For other elements, like the yes and no button in the confirmation dialog, if the component doesn't provide the option for users to customize the content, we could only try to check whether there's a built-in feature for localization.
And this is what I found in DevExtreme DataGrid, it provides us the supoport for localization. Here's the supported language message(using Dictionaries)

If we want to apply localization to all pages, we could set the scripts and DevExpress.localization.locale("de"); in _layout.cshtml. Here's a sample.
<head>
...
    @* reference dictionaries *@
    <script src="~/js/devextreme/localization/dx.messages.de.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/devextreme/localization/dx.messages.es.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
    DevExpress.localization.locale("de");
</script>


I'll try it , I tried it before on the _Layout.cshtml but it didn't work. but I didn't put my configuration in the  and I guess it not the problem, I think it because we working on abp platform which has a different structure I guess. Thank you so much

Thank you for your kind reply. Could you pls share your ultimate solution here if you found my post doesn't work for you and you used another workaround? Just like what you said, the solution in the end might relate to your enviornment. Because what we could get from the official dev blog is like what I shared. Thank you once again in advance.
